# Volume and surface area of solid of revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I'm having some troubles setting this calculus problem. I need to find the volume and the area of the solid resulting from the rotation about the $x$ axis of the figure given by

1. the $x$-axis
2. the curve $y^2 = x + 1$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 0$ and $y \geq 0$.
3. the semicircle given by the equation $x^2 + (y - \frac 12)^2 = \frac 14$  for $x \geq 0.$

For the volume given by the rotation of $y^2 = x + 1$, I solved for $y$ and got:

$V_1 = \pi\int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{x + 1}^2 dx = \frac \pi2$.

For the volume given by the rotation of the semicircle I also solved for y but I get this rather ugly integral to evaluate:

$V_2 = \pi\int_0^\frac 12 (\frac 12 + \sqrt{\frac 14 + x^2})^2 dx$  wich I don't know how to solve. My guess is that the resulting volument is $V = V_1 + V_2$. Is my work correct so far? How do I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work for $V_1$ looks fine, but for $V_2$ I think you want

$\displaystyle V_2=\int_0^{1/2}\pi\left((R(x))^2-(r(x))^2\right)dx=\int_0^{1/2}\pi\left(\bigg(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x^2}\bigg)^2-\bigg(\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x^2}\bigg)^2\right)dx$

$\displaystyle\hspace{.2 in}=\int_0^{1/2}\pi\left(2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x^2}\right)dx=2\pi\int_0^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x^2}dx$.

Now you can use the fact that this integral represents $\frac{1}{4}$ of the area of a circle, or use trig substitution.

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated. I do have some questions regarding your solution. I don't understand why do we need to subtract the $r(x)$ term in the integral. Also, it is unclear to me how you were able to conclude that the integral represents $\frac 14$ of the area of the circle. Would you mind explain this to me?

Comment: We are taking the volume generated by revolving the region under the top half of the semicircle, and then subtracting the volume generated by revolving the region under the bottom half of the semicircle.  (This gives the volume generated by rotating the region inside the semicircle.)  In the last part, you can use that $\int_0^{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$ gives the area between half of a semicircle with radius $a$ and the x-axis, so it equals $\frac{1}{4}$ the area of a circle.

Comment: It makes perfect sense now! Thank you!